# Are there any tighter bounds on the mean number of orthogonally connected components in a binary random rectangular grid?

Tags: probability, connectedness, upper-lower-bounds, means

Question 17 of the set of 20 probability problems at [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135A/resources/chpr.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Egravner/MAT135A/resources/chpr.pdf) provides bounds of $\tfrac{mn}{8}$ and $\tfrac{(m+2)(n+2)}{6}$ for the mean number of orthogonally connected components of an $m$ by $n$ rectangular grid whose squares are randomly (independently and equiprobably) coloured black or white.

Are there any known tighter bounds than this? Or results about any interesting variants of this problem?